# Fading navigation controller title in/out

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, title, fade

I have set my navigation controller's title with the title property. I would like the title to be able to fade in and out in response to some action performed by the user.

My current solution is to provide the navigation controller with a custom titleView, and I would animate the alpha change of that view whenever I want the title to fade. This works, but is creating another problem: I cannot center align the title since the left bar item and the right bar item are varied in width.

Therefore, I am looking for an alternate solution. Is there another way to fade the navigation controller title without using a custom title view?

**EDIT**: I have received some answers showing how to do this by adding subviews. Although that does enable the fade in/out feature I want, I would like to avoid using subviews as I ran into a problem when implementing that solution.

Is there something built into the navigation objects that allows the fading of the title? I have already done some research, and gauging form the responses thus far, I'm guessing there isn't. I'm just posting as a last resort, just incase anyone knows of a way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quick and dirty: You should be able to add a custom label to the navigation bar via

```
[navigationBar addSubview:yourLabel];
```

Just setup the label's frame to be centered within the navigation bar and modify its alpha value as you did before. However, this is a real hack and I'm not sure how it behaves when you're pushing and popping view controllers.

EDIT:

Ok, here you go. First assume we have a navigation bar holding a navigation item with the **title property** (not the titleView property) as well as the left and right bar button item set.

```
UINavigationBar* bar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:bar];

UINavigationItem* anItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"HeyHey"];
UIBarButtonItem* leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem* rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];
anItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;
anItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem;
bar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:anItem];
[leftItem release];
[rightItem release];
[anItem release];
```

Now you can fade the title view like so:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[[[bar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I don't know if the title view is always at index 0, but you can check for your particular case using

```
for (UIView* aView in bar.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@", aView);
}
```

For the title view you will see something like

```
<UINavigationItemView: 0x7566530; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x75665e0>>
```

Comment: How would you "setup the label's frame to be centered"? If you mean I shuld set the label's frame such that its center point is in the middle of the navigation bar, that leads to the  other problem I have: Since the left and right bar buttons are not of the same width, my title cannot use up all the space in the navigation bar AND be centered. Don't know if that is explained clearly enough, but I think this is a separate question that I should ask about.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. I don't really get your centering issue. To summarize what I understood: When you use the title property, the title is centered on the bar, but you cannot fade it. On the other hand, when you use the titleView property you can fade the title, but you cannot center it properly. Is that correct? Another option that comes to my mind is using the title property to set the title and then try to blindly poke around in the navigation bar's subviews array to get a reference to the corresponding label's view. But I'm not sure if this will work out.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Thats exactly what I had in mind as well, though I didn't think that would be a very "proper" way to do it. I guess there really isn't another way to do it. Accepting this as it is the best working answer, but it still feels like a hack.

Comment: Well, indeed it is a hack. And it's not guaranteed to still work after SDK updates. But as you said there (probably) is no other way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with @ImaginaryCake comment: Tweaking the **title** property *sounds like a hack*. The proper way is to use the **titleView** instead of iterating through the `UINavitationBar -subviews` and hope it will survive SDK updates.

Quick & clean in only 2 steps ; From a UIViewController, do:

**Step 1**: Change the `titleView` for your `navigationItem`.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = ({
    UILabel * titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
    [titleView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [titleView setText:@"HeyHey"];

    titleView;
});
```

**Step 2**: Animate at will.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    self.navigationItem.titleView.alpha = 0.5f;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful for u....

```
fade.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
 {

     UINavigationBar *navigationbar;

     NSTimer * timer;
     UILabel * ll;
      UILabel * l2;
 }

@property(nonatomic,retain) UINavigationBar *navigationbar;


@end

fade.m

#define FADE_IN_RATE        2.0/100.0
#define FADE_OUT_RATE       2.0/200.0
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ll.alpha = 0.0;
    l2.alpha =1.0;
    ll = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    l2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    l2.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    ll.text = @"Name";
    ll.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    ll.frame = CGRectMake(115, 10, 60, 20);
    l2.frame = CGRectMake(115, 10, 60, 20);
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:ll];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:l2];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadeScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)fadeScreen
{

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(fadeTimerEvent) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}

- (void)fadeTimerEvent
{

    if (ll.alpha >= 2)
    {
                // At this point, layer1 is now visible  
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;    

    }
    else
    { 

        // Fade lower layer in (increase alpha)
         ll.alpha += FADE_IN_RATE;

        // Fade upper layer out (decrease alpha)
          l2.alpha -= FADE_OUT_RATE;
    }
}
```

Regards,
CNSivakumar

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant in my answer. How does this behave if the navigation bar is coupled to a navigation controller and you push a view controller on the stack?

Comment: I think this would enable the fading functionality I want. However, it requires adding a subview to the navigation bar, which is what I want to avoid. Sorry if I didn't make that too clear in the question, I'll update it.

Comment: Do not add undocumented subviews to `navigationController.navigationBar`. Use the `navigationItem.titleView`. That what `titleView` is for, and that is the only way to ensure cross-iOS functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` property of `UIViewController` is just a `NSString`. You need to add your custom view to your NavigationBar.

> title
>
> A localized string that represents the
>   view that this controller manages.
>
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString
>   *title
>
> Discussion
>
> Subclasses should set the title to a
>   human-readable string that represents
>   the view to the user. If the receiver
>   is a navigation controller, the
>   default value is the top view
>   controller’s title.